# Python Django- Not Returning a Valid Result

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am generating all possible combinations for the given scrambled letters and storing it in a list. Then, I'm checking if words from that list are in my database. Although, the word is in the database, it is not returning so.

example for result list:

```
    result = ['aargh', 'raagh', 'hraag']
```

Although there is a word called aargh in my database, its not returning it.

```
for r in result:
    # print(r)
    try:
        actual = Dictionary.objects.get(word=r)
        print(actual.word)
    except:
        actual = 'Not found'
        print("Actual Word " + str(actual))
```

I have words stored in 'Dictionary' Table. What is wrong here?

Comment: Actually, where is your `print()` function lies? Inside for loop? or after for loop?

Comment: inside the loop after try and except

Comment: did you tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265096/8283848)

Comment: yes. Didn't work

Comment: can you add the result of `Dictionary.objects.values_list('word',flat=True)` ?

Comment: check my answer bellow with `iexact`, otherwise, check your database to see actually you have data

Comment: Ok, my database had word with extra space. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check wheter the word exists or not:

```
for r in result:
    actual = Dictionary.objects.filter(word__iexact=r).first()
    if actual:
         print(actual.word)
         actual = actual.word
    else:
         actual = 'Not found'
    print("Actual Word " + str(actual))
```

Comment: ok I figured it out. Thanks. My database had words with an extra space so exact didn't word.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `icontains`

**Ex:**

```
actual = Dictionary.objects.get(word__icontains=r)
```

**[Info on icontains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#icontains)**

Comment: icontains is getting the words similar to it. But I want to check for the exact word, but when I tried iexact result was  Not found

Comment: You can use `contains` or `iexact`